# Use prototype.js and jqplot for graphs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, jqplot

I al having trouble using AND prototype.js (for appear() and fade() function in menu) AND jqplot for drawing graphs.

When I load external js files like this, then prototype works but I have no jqplot graph (case A) :

```
<script src="includes/scriptaculous/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.jqplot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="includes/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/dist/jquery.jqplot.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.pointLabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.js"></script>
```

When I first load the jqplot files and then the prototype files, then I have a graph but no navigation in my menu's (case B)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

In case A I get the error :

TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function
TypeError: element.getStyle is not a function

In case B I get the error :

TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function

How can I use both ??

Thanks.

Comment: For some reason I can not copy/paste my situation B, it deletes most of the javascript rules. But it comes down to this : the 2 first rules (prototype.js and scriptaculous.js) go to the bottom.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? In Chrome you can press F12 and in Firefox press control + shift +k. I haven't worked with prototype.js but maybe you need to do a jquery.noconflict after loading the jquery library: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Using Firefox. The errors I posted are the errors that I have taken from Firebug.

Comment: Have tried 2 different ways of jquery.noconflict but still the same result : I have a graph but my prototype appear() and fade() are no longer working. Error remains : TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function TypeError: element.getStyle is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

load jQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="includes/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Run `noconflict()`

```
<script language=javascript">jQuery.noConflict()</script>
```

load Prototype and Scripty

```
<script src="includes/scriptaculous/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="includes/scriptaculous/scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then load everything else. Also it looks like you are double loading jQuery, which will cause problems.

Also for the error

```
$(...).ready is not a function
```

In this situation `$()` is the Prototype method - and this is trying to run the jQuery `ready()` method - find this and change to

```
jQuery(...).ready
```